# In R, unexpected result from using group_by() and summarise() in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, summarization, group-summaries

I don't quite understand how some of the groupings and summaries are built in R using dplyr package.

With the reproducible example below I'm trying to first group by (PN,GOT,HID) to count distinct instances of PC1. I then regroup by (PN,GOT) to sum over the distinct instances of PC1, based on the second grouping. This process seems to work for the total sums, except that for mean(TC) I get the mean of the entire data frame when I would expect to see the means by groupings of (PN,GOT). What am i missing to get those means of (PN,GOT), while not losing the sums over PC1 that I've built?  I would appreciate some explanation of where I'm going wrong here.

```
PN<- c("Mazda","Mazda","Datsun","Hornet","Hornet","Valiant","Duster","Merc","Merc","Merc","Merc","Merc",
       "Merc","Merc","Fiat","Honda","Toyota","Toyota","Dodge","AMC","Fiat")
GOT<- c("A","A","B","C","C","A","D","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","A","D","B","B","C","E","A")
HID<- c("Mazda_H1","Mazda_H1","Datsus_H1","Hornet_H1","Hornet_H2","Valiant_H1","Duster_H1","Merc_H1","Merc_H1","Merc_H1",
        "Merc_H2","Merc_H2","Merc_H3","Merc_H4","Fiat_H1","Honda_H1","Toyota_H1","Toyota_H2","Dodge_H1","AMC_H1","Fiat_H1")
PIC<- c("BB","BB","BB","BB","AA","AA","AA","BA","BA","BA",
        "AA","BB","BB","BB","BB","AA","AA","AA","BA","BA","BA")
TC <- c(110,110,93,175,175,105,245,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,33,52,97,97,150,150,33)
Int <- c(16.46,17.02,18.61,19.44,17.02,20.22,15.84,20.00,22.90,18.30,18.90,
         17.40,17.60,18.00,19.47,18.52,19.90,20.01,16.87,17.30,18.90)
PC1<- c("", "","G1","C1","","G1","", "G1","G1","C1","C1","","","","Z1","Z1","Z1","Z1","","","G1")

df<-data.frame(PN,GOT,HID,PIC,TC,Int,PC1)

df

df%>% filter(PC1!="") %>%
  group_by(PN, GOT, HID) %>%
  summarize(new = n_distinct(PC1)) %>%
  group_by(PN, GOT) %>%
  mutate(TOT_new = sum(new),
            meanTC = mean(TC))
```

I think the answer I'm looking for is something looking like this:

```
       PN    GOT        HID   TOT_new meanTC
   <fctr> <fctr>     <fctr>   <int>  <dbl>
1  Datsun      B  Datsus_H1     1     93
2    Fiat      A    Fiat_H1     2     33
3   Honda      D   Honda_H1     1     52
4  Hornet      C  Hornet_H1     1    175
5    Merc      B    Merc_H1     3     62
6  Toyota      B  Toyota_H1     2     97
7 Valiant      A Valiant_H1     1    105
```

or at least this:

```
       PN    GOT        HID   new TOT_new meanTC
   <fctr> <fctr>     <fctr> <int>   <int>  <dbl>
1  Datsun      B  Datsus_H1     1       1     93
2    Fiat      A    Fiat_H1     2       2     33
3   Honda      D   Honda_H1     1       1     52
4  Hornet      C  Hornet_H1     1       1    175
5    Merc      B    Merc_H1     2       3     62
6    Merc      B    Merc_H2     1       3     62
7  Toyota      B  Toyota_H1     1       2     97
8  Toyota      B  Toyota_H2     1       2     97
9 Valiant      A Valiant_H1     1       1    105
```

Comment: When you first `group_by(PN,GOT,HID)` and summarize, the non-grouped variables are lost. If you step through just the first few commands through `summarize`, you'll see what is happening. Perhaps you should do separate group/summary pipes and `left_join` the results? (It would help if you provide your expected output.)

Comment: @r2evans: i'll post an expected result shortly - thanks. Is there any way to keep, or call back, the lost variables for cases where one would like to go back and forth between different summaries?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to find out. Not seeing anything, I'll stick by my first suggestion of multiple pipes (group/summarize `df` once, then do a completely separate group/summarize on `df` again, then join them together).

Answer (score 2):

As commented by @r2evans, the reason you get a global mean is *TC* column is dropped during the first summarize stage. Besides the `join` option suggested in the comment, you can also pass the `TC` column info forward in the first summary stage by calculating two intermediate variables:

```
df %>% filter(PC1 != "") %>%

    group_by(PN, GOT, HID) %>%
    # create two columns with the sum and length of TC in each group which you can use later
    # for average calculation
    summarize(new = n_distinct(PC1), n = n(), TC_sum = sum(TC)) %>%

    group_by(PN, GOT) %>%
    summarise(TOT_new = sum(new), meanTC = sum(TC_sum)/sum(n))

# Source: local data frame [7 x 4]
# Groups: PN [?]

#       PN    GOT TOT_new meanTC
#   <fctr> <fctr>   <int>  <dbl>
#1  Datsun      B       1     93
#2    Fiat      A       2     33
#3   Honda      D       1     52
#4  Hornet      C       1    175
#5    Merc      B       3     62
#6  Toyota      B       2     97
#7 Valiant      A       1    105
```

Comment: I like this better than a double-pipeline ... it works with `sum` and `sum`-related stats, though you might need alternate solutions when aggregates don't work as well (e.g., `median`).

Comment: @r2evans Right, in that case. There's probably not an easy way to do this without a join.

Comment: @Psidom: Shouldn't this be grouping by PN and GOT. Why would there be duplicates in those columns (E.g. Merc and Toyota) - those two should have been grouped into one with one value in each of TOT_new and meanTC. Seems to do that the mutate() needs to change to summarise().

Comment: Yes. If you don't need the intermediate `new` column, it would be better to use summarize, and it makes the code shorter also.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), specify the logical condition in 'i' (`PC1 != ""`), grouped by 'PN', 'GOT', 'HID', we get the `length` of `unique`elements of 'PC1 ('new'), number of elements per group (`.N`), and `sum` of 'TC', then grouped by 'PN', 'GOT', we assign the `sum` of 'new' and ratio of `sum` of 'TC_sum' with `sum` of 'n' to 'TOT_new' and 'meanTC'.  Assign the columns that are not needed to `NULL`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[PC1 != "", .(new = uniqueN(PC1), n = .N, TC_sum = sum(TC)) ,.(PN, GOT, HID)
       ][, c("TOT_new", "meanTC") := .(sum(new), sum(TC_sum)/sum(n)) ,.(PN, GOT)
         ][, c("n", "TC_sum") := NULL][]
#        PN GOT        HID new TOT_new meanTC
#1:  Datsun   B  Datsus_H1   1       1     93
#2:  Hornet   C  Hornet_H1   1       1    175
#3: Valiant   A Valiant_H1   1       1    105
#4:    Merc   B    Merc_H1   2       3     62
#5:    Merc   B    Merc_H2   1       3     62
#6:    Fiat   A    Fiat_H1   2       2     33
#7:   Honda   D   Honda_H1   1       1     52
#8:  Toyota   B  Toyota_H1   1       2     97
#9:  Toyota   B  Toyota_H2   1       2     97
```

Comment: could this method be used to bring back original columns of df that were not introduced right away in the beginning? Your explanation is clear to me, thanks.

Comment: @val  You can do a join with this dataset.  If you notice the dataset, it is only having 9 rows where as the original dataset have more rows.  So, it depends on which values you want to have it in the output

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to make it work, based on some of the comments above. But it looks redundant.

```
df%>% filter(PC1!="") %>%
  group_by(PN, GOT, HID) %>%
  summarize(new = n_distinct(PC1),
            meanTC = mean(TC)) %>%
  group_by(PN, GOT) %>%
  mutate(TOT_new = sum(new),
         meanTC = mean(meanTC))%>%
  select(-HID)

       PN    GOT   new meanTC TOT_new
   <fctr> <fctr> <int>  <dbl>   <int>
1  Datsun      B     1     93       1
2    Fiat      A     2     33       2
3   Honda      D     1     52       1
4  Hornet      C     1    175       1
5    Merc      B     2     62       3
6    Merc      B     1     62       3
7  Toyota      B     1     97       2
8  Toyota      B     1     97       2
9 Valiant      A     1    105       1
```